# Interrupt multiple threads on the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupted-exception

I have 3 threads on a frame and when I press the "Exit" button I want o stop the threads which are currently running and after that to close the frame with the program. For that I created an array where I have all the Threads of the frame and when the button "Exit" is pressed the program iterates over the array and if is there any thread running I interrupt it. The problem with my approch is that the program stops only 1 thread, not all of them. So, even though the frame is closed, there will be 2 threads running on the background.

Here is my program:

```
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.Thread.State;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ProgramInterface extends JFrame {

    private JButton stopThreadsAndExit;

    private CounterThread[] counterThreadsArray = new CounterThread[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgramInterface();
    }

    public ProgramInterface() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        addCounterThreadsToArray();
        addThreadsOnTheFrame();
        stopThreadsAndExit = new JButton("Exit");
        addActionToExitButton();
        add(stopThreadsAndExit);
        setFrameSettings();

    }

    private void setFrameSettings() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addThreadsOnTheFrame() {
        for (CounterThread counter : counterThreadsArray) {
            add(counter);
        }
    }

    public void addActionToExitButton() {
        stopThreadsAndExit = new JButton("Exit");

        stopThreadsAndExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        exit();
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });

    }

    public void exit() {
        for (CounterThread counter : counterThreadsArray) {
            if (counter.isRunnable()) {
                counter.interruptThread();
            }
        }
        dispose();
    }

    private void addCounterThreadsToArray() {
        counterThreadsArray[0] = new CounterThread("Thread 01");
        counterThreadsArray[1] = new CounterThread("Thread 02");
        counterThreadsArray[2] = new CounterThread("Thread 03");
    }
}

class CounterThread extends JPanel {

    Thread counter;

    private String threadName;
    private JButton startThread;

    public CounterThread(String threadString) {
        this.threadName = threadString;
        initializesCounterThread();
        addActionToStartButton();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(startThread);
    }

    public void addActionToStartButton() {
        startThread = new JButton("Start " + threadName);
        startThread.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void initializesCounterThread() {
        counter = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            throw new InterruptedException();
                        }
                        System.out.println(threadName + " generated " + i);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void interruptThread() {
        counter.interrupt();
    }

    public boolean isRunnable() {
        return counter.getState() == State.RUNNABLE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check getState on the thread, you shouldn't have to care if it's currently running or not. Just call interrupt on it.

When you call interrupt on a thread that just sets a flag on that instance. That flag gets checked when the thread does certain things, like wait or sleep, or when the thread explicitly calls isInterrupted (which you are doing). So you don't need to care what state the thread is in.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. What do you think about code? Is the business logic alright I have to improve it?

Comment: @Rusu: you might consider using an executorservice.